# Jinja2 and HTML Div tag

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

I have an html file which I am rendering with jinja2 in python, which has some div sections like

```
<div id="imdb">
{{imdb_output}}
</div>
```

Now even when the value of imdb_output variable is returned None from its function in python file, as expected HTML still displays the div section although with no content, but with its css!

But what do I need to do **so that even the empty div section does not appear if imdb_output has no values to display**?? Do I need to add some JS?

**Please help!**

Here is a screenshot of the problem:-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIhzH.jpg

Comment: I may not have understood the problem, could please rephrase the problem, or give more information ? the actual code of the view and template might help.

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
{% if imdb_output %}
    <div id="imdb">
        {{imdb_output}}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

You should read [jinja2 documentation for template designers](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/)

Answer (score 3):

Just check if imdb_output is empty:

```
{% if imdb_output %}
  <div id="imdb">
    {{imdb_output}}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```